# Quantum computing in finance - list of articles

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request, quantum-computing-for-finance

I am trying to find application of a quantum computing in finance. So far I found these papers:

1. [Quantum computing for finance: Overview and prospects](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03890)
2. [Quantum computational finance: quantum algorithm for portfolio optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03975)
3. [Efficient quantum algorithm for solving travelling salesman problem: An IBM quantum experience](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10928)
4. [Towards Pricing Financial Derivatives with an IBM Quantum Computer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05803)
5. [Quantum computational finance: Monte Carlo pricing of financial derivatives](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.00109)
6. [Quantum Risk Analysis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.06893)
7. [Credit Risk Analysis using Quantum Computers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.03044)

**My question is: do you know about other possible application of quantum computing in finance, banking, companies finanace management or general business area?**

Comment: Here's a recent survey by people at QC Ware: [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.06492).

Comment: @smapers: Thanks, that is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two more papers that may be of interest:

1. [A Quantum Algorithm For Linear PDEs Arising In Finance](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.02753)
2. [Dynamic Portfolio Optimization with Real Datasets Using
   Quantum Processors and Quantum-Inspired Tensor Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.00017)

Answer (score 1):

There are many Qiskit notebooks on quatum computers application in different areas, including finance, in IBM Q web interface.

**For application in finance, click on icon Qiskit Notebooks, then folder Advanced -> Aqua -> Finance.**

Here is also website dedicated to quantum computing application in finance: [Quantum for Quants](http://www.quantumforquants.org/).