# What are the getting-started-resources for quantum finance?

Tags: resource-request, applications, quantum-computing-for-finance

What are suitable books, websites or learning material you can advice to get started with quantum finance?

Comment: This may help: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9576/quantum-computing-in-finance-list-of-articles

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quantum computing in finance - list of articles](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9576/quantum-computing-in-finance-list-of-articles)

Comment: Super cool list thanks 